# How to protect against SQL Injection with pandas read_gbq

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery, sql-injection

How do I use pandas_gbq.read_gbq safely to protect against SQL Injections as I cannot in the docs find a way to parametrize it

I've looked at the docs at a way to parametrize as well as googles website and other sources.

`df_valid = read_gbq(QUERY_INFO.format(variable), project_id='project-1622', location='EU')` Where query looks like `SELECT name, date FROM table WHERE id = '{0}'`

I can input p' or '1'='1 and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Google BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#query-config), you have to use a specified configuration with `SQL` parameterized statement:

```
import pandas as pd

sql = "SELECT name, date FROM table WHERE id = @id"

query_config = {
    'query': {
        'parameterMode': 'NAMED',
        'queryParameters': [
            {
                'name': 'id',
                'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
                'parameterValue': {'value': 1}
            }
        ]
    }
}

df = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id='project-1622', location='EU', configuration=query_config)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had figured out that I needed something like that and I did it slightly differently but I can see this would have worked.